# Text indented by 4 spaces isn't completely shown as code

Tags: support, code-formatting, markdown

I have recently asked this question: [Error while loading custom Android View: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060007 type #0x12 is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26956000)

I have copied the exception's stack trace from InteliJ Console, and I've made sure that it is correctly indented with at least 4 spaces. However, only the first part is shown as code, the rest as normal text:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines are using *non-breaking spaces* in the first column rather than regular spaces:

```
>>> u'''\
...             at myapp.music.organizer.SmallPlayerView.<init>(SmallPlayerView.java:46)
...             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
...             at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
... '''.splitlines()[1]
u'\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0\xa0 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)'
```

Those are [U+00A0 NON-BREAK SPACE](http://codepoints.net/U+00A0) characters, and those are not recognised as indentation for Markdown purposes.

Remove those and use actual spaces to fix this; I've done so now.

Comment: Okay, but why don't I see that that are not real spaces? And why did the first lines work and the last ones not?

Comment: @msrd0: I don't know how you produced this result; from line 9 onwards almost all spaces have been replaced.

Comment: I had all lines copied from InteliJ's console (that was showing Android Logcat), only the first line I have indented manually

Comment: @msrd0: then I guess this is a question for the InteliJ developers; why are they using no-break spaces here?

Comment: The interesting thing is that not all of the spaces were non-breaking spaces ...

Comment: Perhaps the part that used regular spaces was fully visible in the console, the rest needed scrolling to reach?

Comment: No, all needed scrolling, that were 5 nested exceptions with only the one I posted interesting